# Find row which has one cell similar and other cell different than in another row

Tags: excel-formula

Let's say I have this:

```
   A   B
1  10  20
2  12  30
3  25  15
4  40  30
```

How do I find the row which have same value in column B and different value for column A when compared to all the rows above or below ?

I want to find this cell:

A2:B2

Comment: You can use `=A2&B2` and highlight duplicates and sort using the column B. Then also mark column B with duplicates and you should have both of these columns highlighted. In cases where they aren't, that's your answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also highlight the whole range and remove duplicates and it will remove all cases where the data repeats, but without more info for what you're actually trying to do, it's difficult to say the best approach for you. Can you share what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: NO revision necessary

Following feedback I have tested this equation (below) with 20k rows (link below) - happy to report back results as expected/all still in order.  No changes necessary/warranted.  This function works just fine/as expected. Beaut!

Explanation:

When testing large samples of data of type 'integer' (say) that range a common order of magnitude/size (i.e. have material probability of re-occurring), the probability of obtaining a unique value for field A (col B, below screenshot) reduces, due to the law of large numbers (variance is what leads to unique values, and this reduces as the sample size increases).

As a consequence, one may encounter results = !Calc# which simply means 'no unique values could be found in col A (or they could but only for when col C was also unique - although the probability of this is remote, it's mainly due to numerous other cells in respective columns containing identical data.  Throw a negative 100 in column A (assuming all other values are positive real/integer number plane), and you should see my eqn. below return '-100' and whatever the corresponding 'col-C' data is (assuming that is not unique too, as I have mentioned)...

NOW - back to the solution already! :)

---

### ORIGINAL SOLN:

This will give you back every such combination (besides {12,30} there is also {40,30}):

```
=FILTER(B2:B5&"-"&C2:C5,(COUNTIFS(B2:B5,"="&$B$2:$B$5)=1)*(COUNTIFS(C2:C5,"="&$C$2:$C$5)>1))
```

OneDrive excel-linked spreadsheet for your convenience [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j961UmMUkthowCZO-d?e=FUhZwQ), taking *careful* note of restrictions per 1st comment to this proposed soln.

**Screenshot**

[image: Excel exhibit - all necessary info to recreate this screenshot has been provided herein in case you miss expiry date]

**Notes**

1. Assumes you have Office 365 version of Excel

Comment: pw=my name in lower case, backwards.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Sorry for late response. I tried your formula and it gives #CALC! error, and tried to open your link and it says: This item might not exist or is no longer available

Comment: Does it matter if column A has values such as:  100,25,68   numbers with comma separated ? I tried to convert all values without comma as is 1002568 and formated as number 1002568.00, but it still gives #CALC error

Comment: Looks like if I have less than 100 rows it will work as expected, but for 10k rows it returns empty array and I fixed the #calc error by simply adding FILTER( ...., 0) for empty array. How to make this working with 10k rows ?

Comment: Take the test case you have with 10k rows, and pick 5 random cells in col B - e.g. A235, A1115, A5, A985, and A5.  Overwrite their existing values with 5 unique values that you can be sure don't occur anywhere else in that column (e.g. "ginko belobo", -2x10^4, "BatmanSucks", "Peter Rabbit" and whatever.), and include the same value (e.g. 1) in each of the corresponding adjacent cells (col C), e.g. 1 or something.  What do you see now?

Comment: (PS - have updated the onedrive link - you can see answers as expected for 20k rows - your test case had no unique values in col B which is why you got a #Calc! - upvote if this makes sense for my development (downvote otherwise! :)

Comment: @Fed: any feedback on this?